# How to disable right click "delete" option on worksheets tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a way to disable the right click "delete" option on the excel worksheets tab at the bottom to prevent users from be able to delete a worksheet. I know that protecting the worksheet/workbook will disable this but what if I want to disable it while protecting or not protecting all together?

```
Application.CommandBars("Ply").FindControl(ID:=847).Enabled = False
```

will disable it but if the workbook/worksheet had a password protected, when un protecting it, the command will be disregard and the delete worksheet can still be done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702186/how-to-prevent-user-from-deleting-sheet-but-leave-all-else-open and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645870/prevent-user-from-deleting-a-particular-sheet

Comment: those don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
' To Activate right click on tab - run the following
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = False
End Sub

' To Deactivate right click on tab - run the following code
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.CommandBars("Ply").Enabled = True
End Sub
```